# Flutter Riverpod Loading State

Tags: flutter, state-management, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod for state management for my Flutter app but i stuck at loading state. I want to set whole state to the loading state but Riverpod's loading state expect me to return widget.

```
 _getVideoData().when(
                data: (data) {
                  if (data != null) {
                    if (_isInterstitialLoaded) {
                      _interstitialAd.show();
                    }
                    _showVideo(data.url);
                    return VideoPlayerWidget(
                      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
                      videoDescription: data.description,
                      authorNickname: data.authorNickname,
                      avatar: data.avatar,
                      downloadOnPressed: () async {
                        if (storagePermission.isGranted) {
                          await _saveVideo(data);
                        }
                        if (!storagePermission.isGranted) {
                          if (storagePermission.canRequestPermission) {
                            await storagePermission.checkPermission();
                          } else {
                            await openAppSettings();
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  return const SizedBox.shrink();
                },
                error: (error, _) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text('Deneme'),
                  );
                },
                loading: () {
                  return Image.asset(
                    'assets/gifs/hourglass.gif',
                  );
                },
              )
```

I'm using this rn but it only appears on widget tree. I want to make whole ui waits for the data. Rn it just shows as widget. Here is an example for what i want:

https://pub.dev/packages/loader_overlay

Comment: Hey, could you provide the `_getVideoData` snippet since it's providing the state the error should be there !